# import jellyfish module in redshift UDF

Tags: amazon-redshift

Redshift - python UDF can import built-in as well as several important modules. But I have a function that needs "jellyfish" module.

I tried to implement the steps mentioned here...

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html#udf-importing-custom-python-library-modules

But I guess, importing a module in redshift UDF must be easier. How do I import a third party module in redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct approach. You have to import the library before your UDF can use it. Rough example (not tested):

```
CREATE LIBRARY jellyfish LANGUAGE plpythonu FROM 's3://…

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_jellyfish_levenshtein (a varchar, b varchar) RETURNS int IMMUTABLE as $$ 
    import jellyfish
    jellyfish.levenshtein_distance(a, b)

    return LineSegment(x1, y1, x2, y2).distance()
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Note that Redshift UDFs do not currently allow you to execute C/C++ Python extensions, only pure Python libraries will work.